# Regex for searching or gripping complex passwords in code repos

Tags: regex, linux, grep, notepad++

I need a regex to use with Notepad++ "Find In Files" or with find and grep command on linux
`find $dirs -type f -name '*.php' -o -name '*.sh' -exec grep -rHn "REGEX"`
to make sure no passwords is hard coded in our code repositories 
passwords should at least be 8 characters long and maximum 12 and should at least have one lowercase,uppercase,digit characters and it can have special characters or not

here is an example passwords i want to match

`sH@R3d1nH3re`

`f0llOwUp`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will be pretty much impossible to distinguish a password from any other text/code, but here the RegEx your looking for, which will match match anything but whitespaces, including single and double quotes:

[!-~]{8,12}

If you don't want to include quotes and the password must have quotes around it try this (Not sure if you'll need to escape the start parenthesis, but shouldn't hurt):

['"][!#-&(-~]{8,12}['"]

Note, for the grep, you'll have to use the -P option and escape the double quotes, for example:

grep -P "['\"][!#-&(-~]{8,12}['\"]"

If you wanted to ensure you had at least one lowercase AND at least one uppercase AND at least one digit, you'll have to use lookahead and that's more completed, but this site has an example and explanation at the bottom (Note: I couldn't get the lookaheard working in Notepad++):
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s19.html#validation-password-variations